# Парсинг реестра Windows. Powershell

Tags: powershell, реестр, outlook

У меня есть скрипт на powershell, который создает пользователю подпись в outlook и делает ее подписью по умолчанию для определенной учетной записи.
Конкретно следующий кусок кода делает новую подпись подписью по умолчанию:

```
$RegPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"

$DefSign = "MyDefaultSign"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name "New Signature" -Value $DefSign
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name "Reply-Forward Signature" -Value $DefSign
```

В пути реестра видно, что мы идем в определенную ветку *"9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"*
где куча цифр вперемешку с буквами это идентификатор версии Outlook, а "00000002" идентификатор учетной записи. Внутри "00000002" есть ключ Email:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу разобраться, как мне сделать так, чтобы скрипт просматривал все ветки-идентификаторы учетных записей Outlook, затем искал в них значение ключа "Mail" по маске почты, допустим @mymail.com и после обнаружения нужной ветки-идентификатора возвращал путь до нее в эту строчку:

```
$RegPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"
```

Т.е. в конце вместо 00000002 подставлял нужную ветку (00000003, 00000004 и т.д.).

Answer (score 0):

Сделал, решение моей проблемы выглядит вот так:

```
$HomePath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\"
$AccountPath = Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676 -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath } | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Email -match '@mymail.com'} | Select -ExpandProperty PSChildName
$RegPath = $HomePath + $AccountPath
```